# What to do with iText "Unexpected color space /CS0" type of exceptions

Tags: java, exception, pdf, itext, color-space

I have some files generated by unknown source that open just fine in PDF browsers (Reader/Foxit) but iText fails to process them. For particular file I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected colorspace /CS0
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.getComponentsPerPixel(InlineImageUtils.java:238)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.computeBytesPerRow(InlineImageUtils.java:251)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.parseUnfilteredSamples(InlineImageUtils.java:280)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.parseInlineImageSamples(InlineImageUtils.java:320)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.InlineImageUtils.parseInlineImage(InlineImageUtils.java:153)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.processContent(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:370)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.processContent(PdfReaderContentParser.java:79)
```

sometimes /CS0 color space changes to /CS1 through /CS9 (or something similar).

Is it a iText bug (I'm using java 1.7, iText 5.4.1) or are my pdf files just broken? Even if the pdf files are broken is there any way I can fix them? (Adobe Reader seems to do that somehow, but unfortunately opening the file and saving it again does not work).

Comment: Can you share one of those files?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't - I'm dealing with _very_ large set of pdfs and no longer remember which ones caused the problem (which I solved)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PDF specification so I don't know if PDFs I worked with were valid or not. I did however managed to solve the problem by making changes to iText in file com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.InlineIamgeUtils method getComponentsPerPixel(...) from:

```
private static int getComponentsPerPixel(PdfName colorSpaceName, PdfDictionary colorSpaceDic){
        if (colorSpaceName == null)
            return 1;
        if (colorSpaceName.equals(PdfName.DEVICEGRAY))
            return 1;
        if (colorSpaceName.equals(PdfName.DEVICERGB))
            return 3;
        if (colorSpaceName.equals(PdfName.DEVICECMYK))
            return 4;

        if (colorSpaceDic != null){
            PdfArray colorSpace = colorSpaceDic.getAsArray(colorSpaceName);
            if (colorSpace != null){
                if (PdfName.INDEXED.equals(colorSpace.getAsName(0))){
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected color space " + colorSpaceName);
    }
```

to

```
private static int getComponentsPerPixel(PdfName colorSpaceName, PdfDictionary colorSpaceDic){
        if (colorSpaceName == null)
            return 1;
        if (colorSpaceName.equals(PdfName.DEVICEGRAY))
            return 1;
        if (colorSpaceName.equals(PdfName.DEVICERGB))
            return 3;
        if (colorSpaceName.equals(PdfName.DEVICECMYK))
            return 4;

        if (colorSpaceDic != null){
            PdfArray colorSpace = colorSpaceDic.getAsArray(colorSpaceName);
            if (colorSpace != null){
                if (PdfName.INDEXED.equals(colorSpace.getAsName(0))){
                    return 1;
                }
            } /* Begin mod # */ else {
                PdfName tempName = colorSpaceDic.getAsName(colorSpaceName);
                if(tempName != null) return(getComponentsPerPixel(tempName, colorSpaceDic));
            } /* End mod */
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected color space " + colorSpaceName);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't check if the hack is in line with ISO-32000-1, but I uploaded the change to the SVN repository as it looks OK at first sight.

Comment: I'm getting this with iText for Android (com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10), which has this fixed code. I'm getting the error color spaces starting with "/R". For example, "/R9", "/R10", "/R11". It looks like this is trying to do some kind of OCR on embedded images, when there's no "Filter" key in InlineImageDictionary? I dug a bit, and colorSpaceDic.GetAsArray() is returning, in one case, "[/ICCBased, 10, 0, R]". Why is ICCBased an unexpected color space? The problem is that the code as written doesn't just give up on the image... it gives up on the page.

Comment: Interesting, this seems to have been caused by my use of ghostscript to embed fonts. If I'm not running ghostscript, the issues doesn't occur. Entirely possible my case is a ghostscript bug, then.